# multiple tables in 1 query

Tags: php, database, loops, pdo

I have 2 tables in my database:

**Bogie** table:

```
+----------+----------+---------+----------+
| bogie_id | train_id | axle_nr | bogie_nr |
+----------+----------+---------+----------+
|        1 |        1 |       1 |        1 |
|        2 |        1 |       2 |        1 |
|        3 |        1 |       3 |        2 |
|        4 |        1 |       4 |        2 |
+----------+----------+---------+----------+
```

**Axle** table:

```
+---------+----------+------+----------+
| axle_id | train_id | axle | distance |
+---------+----------+------+----------+
|       1 |        1 |    1 |     2500 |
|       2 |        1 |    2 |     5000 |
|       3 |        1 |    3 |     2500 |
+---------+----------+------+----------+
```

Now, i want to show the axles from the bogie table (4) and the distances from the axle table (3)

I made a query (Don't mind the names):

```
function hopethisworks(){
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM axle WHERE train_id = :train_id";
        $sth = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);
        $sth->bindParam(':train_id', $_GET['train_id'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $sth->execute();
        $res['axle'] = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM bogie WHERE train_id = :train_id";
        $sth = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);
        $sth->bindParam(':train_id', $_GET['train_id'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $sth->execute();
        $res['bogie'] = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 

        return $res;
    }
```

Now, when i enter this:

```
$testingggg = $database->hopethisworks();
echo $testingggg['bogie']['axle_nr'];
```

I get the result: "1"

Wich is good becuase the first *axle_nr* in the *bogie* table is 1.

However, i wana show 4 instead of 1.
So i make a loop:

```
 <?php
     $testingggg = $database->hopethisworks();

     foreach($testingggg as $testingggg){
         echo $testingggg['bogie']['axle_nr'];
     }
  ?>
```

I expect the result to be: `1 2 3 4` but instead of that, i get:

*Notice: Undefined index: bogie in...*

How do i remove the error, and show the numbers 1, 2, 3, 4?

**EDIT:**

The join query i had:

```
function axleees() {
        $sql = "SELECT ti.axle_nr, ti.train_id, ti.bogie_nr, uti.axle_id, uti.train_id, uti.axle, uti.distance
                FROM bogie as ti
                JOIN axle as uti
                ON ti.train_id = uti.train_id
                WHERE ti.train_id = :train_id";
        $sth = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);
        $sth->bindParam(":train_id", $_GET["train_id"], PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $sth->execute();
        return $sth->fetchAll();
    }
```

Comment: If you have a foreign key in one table that refers the primary key of the other, use JOIN to get the result in a single query. Read about join: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Comment: I tried an JOIN before. I gave me 12 results while i only had 4 axles in my DB

Comment: Then your join is wrong, or there is no relation between your tables. Notice that you are using fetch, that will only retrive the first row. Use fetchAll insted. Also, use var_dump on your variable to see it's content, it is very useful for debug.

Comment: Post your `join` query

Answer (score 1):

What you're getting here is not what you want to do. When you're executing `hopethisworks()` what you're getting is an array with the first row of bogie and the first row of axle (or the second or the nth, depending on how the mysql orders it)

```
res['bogie']['bogie_id']=1
res['bogie']['train_id']=1
res['bogie']['axel_nr']=1
res['bogie']['bogie_nr']=1

res['axle']['axle_id'] = 1
res['axle']['train_id'] = 1
res['axle']['axle'] = 1
res['axle']['distance'] = 2500
```

That has 2 rows and four elements in each. So, when you call res['bogie']['axle_nr'] the first time it works, because is reading the first row (`res['bogie']`), but the second time it is reading from the second row (`res['axle']`) and then it crashes because you're asking for an index which is not defined there.

For what you want to do, I guess it is reading all the results from the query you should better use a JOIN and then execute a loop like this

```
$i = 0;
$aux = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
while ($aux){
    $res[i]=$aux;
}
```